# Remove header Content-transfer-encoding: 8bit using PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Is it possible to remove Content-transfer-encoding: 8bit from the email headers using PHPMailer?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? In which encoding are you sending it? :s

Comment: I'm writing a domain registration script, if I send the registration form using evolution mail send in plain text it works and domain gets registered, if I send it via PHP Mailer it fails. I do not understand, so i try everthing now. since I noticed if I send using evlution the content transfer encoding is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been a while since I used this, but can you just search the source for where that encoding is set ... its probably either hard coded or in a property, that you'll possibly be able to set.

If not, you can extend that class and override the method(s) you need to. Sorry, I don't have an exact answer.